Arrayformula to SUM matching ID AND when date is between two dates
SUMIFS and/or QUERY inside ARRAYFORMULA
The problem explained above is a simpler, but very close approximation of what I'm trying to do. I'm looking to split up the 12 month year into 24 segments, the first and second part of each month. So essentially its identical to the issue above, except instead of specifying a month, I want to specify instead a range of dates that I can specify. I don't need exactly 24 segments, but for what I'm doing that visually is much better than 12 months. WEEKNUM() is an option, but that splits the year into 52 segments, which is far too many.
Here is an sheet example using slightly modified example data from the example above:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z90lA0DvsnURE2wYgbcXZY9_QRtG42ifV__QSMIrl5Y/edit?gid=646558234#gid=646558234
The other solution was =arrayformula(SUMIF(D3:D20&MONTH(F3:F20); A2:A7&2; E3:E20))
I've tried with DATEVALUE() and that works for single days, but I haven't been able to get anything to work when needing to specify a range. Perhaps DAYS() could be used to compare the date in the data vs the start of the month date, but that still encompasses a range of values 1-15 as opposed to a single value like the answer above. I'm not sure where to go from here.
Below is a link to the actual dataset. Check out cell BZ2 in the tab entitled List where I put the formula =map($A$2:$A,lambda(Σ,map(BZ1:CW1,lambda(Λ,let(x,sumifs('Ref4'!$Q$2:$Q,'Ref4'!$G$2:$G,Σ,'Ref4'!$P$2:$P,">="&Λ,'Ref4'!$P$2:$P,"<"&if(day(Λ)=1,offset(Λ,,1),eomonth(Λ,))),if(x=0,,x))))))
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6nyu3xh0sLvbWjJ_vValAklzeTy72fvv3Cp0pEo--Y/edit?usp=sharing


You may try this single formula in Cell_L2:
=map(K2:K6;lambda(Σ;map(L1:AI1;lambda(Λ;let(x;sumifs(E:E;D:D;Σ;F:F;">="&Λ;F:F;"<"&if(day(Λ)=1;offset(Λ;;1);eomonth(Λ;)));if(x=0;;x))))))


Updated formula:
=map(A2:index(A:A,match(,0/(A:A<>""))),lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,map(BZ1:CW1,lambda(Λ,let(x,index(sumifs('Ref4'!Q:Q,'Ref4'!G:G,Σ,--'Ref4'!P:P,">="&Λ,--'Ref4'!P:P,"<"&if(day(Λ)=1,offset(Λ,,1),eomonth(Λ,)))),if(x=0,,x)))))))



OK, so this works for the simple example dataset that I linked above. However, when I reformat this to my actual dataset, it returns the error "Calculation limit was reached while trying to compute this formula." I have about 1500 rows in the sheet where the formula is being put, and a reference sheet with a similar amount of rows. I turned Iterative Calculations Off and still no change.

Provide realistic dataset to test formulas since I dont see any data in Ref4 tab

Should be fixed now, sorry about that.

Added updated formula in the answer...

Is there a way to incorporate that formula into a header in the first row using ={"example header"; formula_insanity()}? Ideally I'd want to put this in BZ1 but would be fine putting it in BY1 if that were possible. Sorry I didn't specify that in the question first. I tried myself and got the error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows." I really haven't used lambda or Sigma so I'm having a tough time interpreting what is actually going on in the formula.
